# What does two consecutive asterisks in Pointcut expression mean?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I tried to define a pointcut which would match all methods in a class, but it did not work.
I tried hard to find out the reason why. 
And I eventually found the fault point of the pointcut expression I defined.

The following is the beginning of what I defined first. (does not work)

```
@Pointcut("execution(** membership.data.MemberRepository.*(..))")
```

As I had known, the consecutive two asterisks in "execution(**" means any access modifier and any return type, but It never matched some methods that has some kind of return types like this :

```
public List<MemberVO> findByName(String name) { ...
```

On the other hand, It matched another like this:

```
public String print(String str) { ...
```

And the following is the begining of the proper ways of defining it which I found out. these match the above two method signatures and work fine.

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * membership.data.MemberRepository.*(..))")

@Pointcut("execution(* membership.data.MemberRepository.*(..))")
```

What was I missing? I tried hard to find the answer but it never appeared.
Please let me know the exact meaning of "execution(** ".

Addition: The full source of the aspect class

```
@Aspect
public class PerformanceLogger {

    @Pointcut("execution(* membership.data.MemberRepository.*(..))")
    public void performance() {}

    @Around("performance()")
    public Object watchPerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        try {
            long st = System.nanoTime();
            Object obj = jp.proceed();
            System.out.println(jp.toShortString() + " called :" + (System.nanoTime() - st));
            return obj;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a space between the two `*`?

Comment: @Andreas I tried to put a space in between the two like this: "execution(* * .." and it caused an exception while initializing the aspect bean which has the pointcut expression in it.

Comment: Why do you not share full pointcut and method signatures? This way you will not get meaningful answers. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. Oh, and by the way: `**` does not have any meaning at all. This I can already tell you. Your problem is in the part you hide from us.

Comment: @kriegaex Okay, I got it. It was just because I didn't have the source code when I wrote this question and now I'm home with my personal desktop. I added the the full pointcut expression I defined and an aspect class. and the called class, named membership.data.MemberRepository is still not here because it is uselessly too verbose to be written here and the signatures of the methods needed have already been here, "findByName(String name)" and "print(String name)".

Comment: @kriegaex In addition, I first saw the pointcut expression, "execution(** .." which works fine with "public void print(Sting name)" but does not work with "public List<MemberVO> findByName(String name)" in a book, titled Spring in Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment: `**` does not mean anything, you are lucky the parser seems to interpret it as equivalent to `*`, but you cannot be sure. Actually it should yield a syntax error. So please do not use it, it is meaningless. Your assumption about the meaning is just false. `* * blah(..)` also does not work, it is invalid syntax. IMO it should be fixed in the book "Spring in Action", I also found it there. In the whole AspectJ documentation you will not find something like `**`.

As for your question: In order to get all method executions for class `membership.data.MemberRepository` you use the pointcut `execution(* membership.data.MemberRepository.*(..))`. You already found out by yourself.